# How to Convert Exponentiation Number into Fixed Decimal Number in Adobe Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to convert exponential to fixed decimal.
example: 2.5e12 ,0.12323e-11 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function formatIntoFixedValue(value:Object):Object
            {
                var isNegativeNum:Boolean ;
                var isNegativeExp:Boolean;
                var isDecimal:Boolean;
                var splitNums:Array;
                var splitFixedNum:Array;
                var leftDecPlaceCount:Number=0;
                var rightDecPlaceCount:Number=0;
                var exponentNum=0;
                var finalNum:String;
                var valueNum:Number=Number(value);
                var valueStr:String = valueNum.toString();
```

> // is not exponent return

```
            if(valueStr.indexOf("e")<0)
            return valueStr;

            if(valueNum<0)
```

> // Number is negative or not

```
                isNegativeNum=true;
            else
                isNegativeNum=false;

            splitFixedNum= valueStr.split("e");

            if(Number(splitFixedNum[1])<0)
```

> //Exponent is negative or not

```
                isNegativeExp=true;
            else 
                isNegativeExp=false;

            exponentNum=Math.abs(Number(splitFixedNum[1]));//-7
```

> // removing space
>                   splitFixedNum[0]=StringUtil.trimArrayElements(splitFixedNum[0],"");
>
> // removing minus sign from start if exist.
>                   splitFixedNum[0]=splitFixedNum[0].toString().replace("-","");
>
> //  it is removing zeors of start

```
            finalNum=Number(splitFixedNum[0]).toString();
```

> // Is Decimal or Not

```
            if(finalNum.toString().indexOf(".")>=0)
            {
            isDecimal=true;
            }
            else 
            isDecimal=false;
```

> /// exponent is zero

```
            if(exponentNum==0)
            return finalNum;
```

> // if num is decimal 
>                   if(isDecimal) 
>                   {
>                       var expDiff:Number;

```
                splitNums= String(splitFixedNum[0]).split(".");

                splitNums[0]=Number(splitNums[0]).toString();
                if(splitNums[0]!="0")
                {



                finalNum=splitNums[0].toString().concat(splitNums[1]); 
                leftDecPlaceCount=splitNums[0].toString().length;

                }
                else
                {



                finalNum=splitNums[1]; 
                leftDecPlaceCount=0;
                }


                rightDecPlaceCount=splitNums[1].toString().length;

                if(isNegativeExp)
                    expDiff=exponentNum-leftDecPlaceCount;

                else
                    expDiff=exponentNum-rightDecPlaceCount;
```

> //If exp diff  is greater than zero concatenate zeros

```
                if(expDiff>0)
                {
                        var zeros:String="";

                        for(var i:Number=0;i<expDiff;i++)
                            zeros+="0";

                        if(isNegativeExp)   
                        finalNum="0."+zeros+finalNum;
                        else
                        finalNum= finalNum+zeros;   

                }
```

> //If exp diff  is less than zero than move .(dot) between number

```
                else if(expDiff<0)
                {
                    var s:String;
                    expDiff= Math.abs(expDiff);
                    if(isNegativeExp)
                    s =finalNum.substr(0,expDiff)+"."+finalNum.substr(expDiff,finalNum.length);
                    else
                    s =finalNum.substr(0,(leftDecPlaceCount+rightDecPlaceCount)-expDiff)+"."+finalNum.substr((leftDecPlaceCount+rightDecPlaceCount)-expDiff,finalNum.length);
                    finalNum=s;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(isNegativeExp)
                    finalNum= "0."+finalNum;

                }
            }
            else
            {

                        var zeros:String="";

                        for(var i:Number=0;i<exponentNum-finalNum.length;i++)
                            zeros+="0";

                        if(isNegativeExp)   
                        finalNum="0."+zeros+finalNum;
                        else
                        finalNum= finalNum+zeros;
            }   

            if(isNegativeNum)
            finalNum ="-"+ finalNum;

            return finalNum.toString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flash/Flex you can use one of the `NumberFormatter` classes. Below is an example using the Flex 3 (MX) `NumberFormatter`. Take a look at the docs for the API's each one offers, they are a little different from each other.

```
var n:Number = 3 * .0000000001;
trace(n); // 3e-10
var f:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
f.precision=10;
trace(f.format(n)); // 0.0000000003
```

There are 3 NumberFormatter classes, one for pure Flash (non-Flex), one for Flex 3, and the Flex 4 version. The first and last ones will also format the number specific to the user's locale (use comma's instead of periods, where appropriate, etc.).

Here are the links to documentation:

- [Flash NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html)
- [Flex 3 NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/NumberFormatter.html)
- [Flex 4 (Spark) NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/NumberFormatter.html)

Comment: @AsadYarKhan Hi, I'm confused :) You accepted it as the answer, but it's not acceptable? You might specify why it doesn't meet your needs and add that to your question if it's important. Frankly, your question is vague and doesn't state any requirements. Also, these are the standard number formatting classes from Adobe. It's nice that you have a fancier solution, but others should be aware of what is already available. You can unaccept this and accept your own answer by the way, if you do so, please clarify what the differences are so others can benefit.

Comment: and the to.Fixed() function crash on big decimal value. :(

Comment: I modified my code which is availabe in below post with some modification.